# computing distance with respect to a specific column using R

Tags: r, distance, measure

I have a 10 * 10 matrix. I would like to generate a distance matrix with respect to a specific column (column1). How to calculate using R ? Is there any function?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compute `dist` between rows of other columns with respect to 1st column

```
apply(m1[,-1], 2, function(x) dist(cbind(x, m1[,1])))
```

Or if the distance calculation is between columns

```
apply(m1[,-1], 2, function(x) dist(rbind(x, m1[,1])))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
m1 <- matrix(sample(1:30, 10*10, replace=TRUE),10, 10)
```